# Authenticate User Against MySQL Database Not Working

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

A pretty simple thing I'm trying to do here but I'm slamming my head against a wall trying to figure out why it doesn't work. All of the code makes sense to me.

I have a MySQL Database and I have my user data (Username and Password) stored in the database. The password is encrypted via password_hash() function. I know the password successfully hashes because I can see the hash value in the backend of the database on Sequel Pro.

The problem I'm having is trying to get my Login Page to authenticate against that username and password. What's odd also, is that even if I leave the username and password field blank on the login page, the page flickers when I click the submit button as if it were submitting some data but throws no errors on the page or anything.

The `password.php` file you see required at the top of the file is this: https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat

Here is my code in `server.php`

```
<?php
require('password.php');
session_start();

$errors = array();

// connect to the database
$db = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'password', 'mydb');
if (!$db) {
    die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
// LOGIN USER
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
  $usernameLogin = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['usernameLogin']);
  $passwordLogin = $_POST['lpass'];
    $password_encrypted = password_hash($passwordLogin, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

  if (empty($usernameLogin)) {
    array_push($errors, "Username is required");
  }
  if (empty($passwordLogin)) {
    array_push($errors, "Password is required");
  }

  if (count($errors) == 0) {

         $authLogin = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$usernameLogin' AND password='$password_encrypted'";
           $resultLogin = mysqli_query($db, $authLogin);
        if (password_verify($passwordLogin, $password_encrypted)) {
          $_SESSION['username'] = $usernameLogin;
          $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
          header('location: index.php');
        } else {
        array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
        }
    }
  }
}

 ?>
```

Here is my `login.php`

```
<?php include('server.php');
      require('password.php');
 ?>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="createaccountstyle.css">
</head>
<div>

<form method="post" action="login.php" id="msform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <?php include('errors.php'); ?>
  <!-- fieldsets -->
  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Login to Your Account</h2>
    <input type="text" name="usernameLogin" placeholder="Username" />
    <input type="password" name="lpass" placeholder="Password" />
    <button type="submit" name="login" class="login action-button">Login</button><br><br>
  </fieldset>
</form>
<center><div class="fs-title">
<p>
        Not yet a member?<br><a href="createaccount.php">Sign up</a>
    </p>
</div></center>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="createaccount.js"></script>


</html>
```

Comment: you're already querying the user record from db with the **encrypted password** with `$authLogin = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$usernameLogin' AND password='$password_encrypted'";` no need to use `password_verify($passwordLogin, $password_encrypted)` as it will try to rehash it which will result in error.

Comment: also use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in enctype of your form as `multipart/form-data` is only required if you're going to upload a file.

Comment: put `require('password.php');` over `include('server.php');`

Comment: So what would I use in my if statement if the $authLogin already verifies the password? @Cemal

Comment: mysqli_num_rows($authLogin) > 0

Comment: I guess I'm confused as to how I retrieve the hashed password that is stored in the database when doing the verification. @Cemal

Comment: `AND password='$password_encrypted'`

Comment: But I'm trying to compare `$password_enrypted` with what is actually stored in the database. So if `$password_encrypted` is a completely different hashed password, it's not going to equal whatever is stored in the database. That's what doesn't make any sense. I need to compare it with the hashed password that I stored in a variable when the user first created their account. @Cemal

Comment: So essentially I would need this: `$password_encrypted = password_verify($userInputOnLoginForm, $TheHashStoredInTheDatabase)`
But I have no idea how to retreive `$TheHashStoredInTheDatabase`

Comment: @Cemal I might go so far as to do `==1` vs `>0` - there should be only one match, if you get 2 matches, should you continue or freak out?

Comment: I don't know how you store the password in your db but i'd go ahead and say you store it already encrypted/hashed. You encrypt what the user enters with `password_hash` therefore no need to check it against an already hashed password on the db using `password_verify`. There must be only 1 record. If there are 2, it means there are 2 people sharing an account. The rows should be unique by the username.